# Error while inserting polygon coordinates to Mongo DB using geojson and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a beginner in Nodejs and Mongo DB. I am trying to create zones as square shaped polygons. I am using Nodejs for store in DB.

My Mongoose Schema is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var momentTimezone  = require('moment-timezone');
var moment          = require('moment');


const geofencingAreasSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    coordinates: [],    
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: new moment.tz ('Asia/Dubai').format('Y-M-D HH:mm:ss')
   }
});
 geofencingAreasSchema.index({ coordinates:"2d" });  
/**
 * Export Schema
 */
module.exports = mongoose.model('geofencing_areas', geofencingAreasSchema,'geofencing_areas');
```

I am trying to insert coordinates using the following

```
var GeofencingModel = require('../models/geofencing_areas.js');
const Zone = new GeofencingModel({
   name:row.toString()+col.toString(),
   type:'Polygon',
   coordinates : [coordinates],
   created_at: new moment.tz('Asia/Dubai').format('Y-M-D HH:mm:ss')
 });
 Zone.save((err, zones) => {
   if (err) {
     return false;
   } else {
     return true;
   }
});
```

My coordinates array contains

```
[ [ 55.18777533242337, 25.35359425987688 ],
  [ 55.18777533242337, 55.287108408253516 ],
  [ 55.287108408253516, 25.26372890279708 ],
  [ 25.26372890279708, 25.35359425987688 ],
  [ 55.18777533242337, 25.35359425987688 ] ]
```

After running I am getting the error like

> { MongoError: Can't extract geo keys: { _id:
>   ObjectId('5bb6ff2fddff79200cd5d5ef'
>       ), created_at: new Date(1538714135000), name: "11", coordinates: [ [ [ 55.187775
>       33242337, 25.35359425987688 ], [ 55.18777533242337, 55.28710840825352 ], [ 55.28
>       710840825352, 25.26372890279708 ], [ 25.26372890279708, 25.35359425987688 ], [ 5
>       5.18777533242337, 25.35359425987688 ] ] ], __v: 0 }  Point must only contain numeric elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var momentTimezone  = require('moment-timezone');
var moment          = require('moment');


const geofencingAreasSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    loc: {
      type: {type: String},
      coordinates: []
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: new moment.tz ('Asia/Dubai').format('Y-M-D HH:mm:ss')
   }
});     
 geofencingAreasSchema.index({loc: '2dsphere'});
/**
 * Export Schema
 */
module.exports = mongoose.model('geofencing_areas', geofencingAreasSchema,'geofencing_areas');
```

Insert function

```
const Zone = new GeofencingModel({
   name:row.toString()+col.toString(),
   loc:{type:'Polygon',coordinates : [coordinates]},
   created_at: new moment.tz('Asia/Dubai').format('Y-M-D HH:mm:ss')
 });
 Zone.save((err, zones) => {
   if (err) {
      return false;
   } else {
     return respose;
   }
});
```